# Pass multiple arguments from php to python?

Tags: python, php, html

```html
<html>
   <body>
      <head>
         <title>HTML Forms</title>
      </head>
      <p>Add your details:</p>
      <form name="form" method="get">
         Number 1:<br> <input type="number" name="first">
         <br>
         Number 2:<br> <input type="number" name="second">
         <br>
         Number 3:<br> <input type="number" name="third">
         <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" />
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

```php
<?php
$var1 =  $_GET['first'];
$var2 =  $_GET['second'];
$var3 =  $_GET['third'];
$command = escapeshellcmd("python total.py $var1 $var2 $var3");
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo ($output);

?>
```

```py
import sys

num_1 = sys.argv[1]

num_2 = sys.argv[2]

num_3 = sys.argv[3]

print("total:", num_1+num_2+num_3)
```

I have shared the code I am using. I want to get the values from user using the HTML code and read it using PHP. Then pass the values from PHP script to python script, do the task and display the output.

For some reason I am unable to do that. Can someone help me?

Comment: It would help if you disclose what exactly doesn't work, what the error messages are, etc.

Comment: There aren't any error messages. The chrome page is just empty. It's not displaying anything

Comment: Is the way I'm passing the variables from PHP script to python the problem?

Comment: At that point I would start debugging either program and see what is actually in these variables.

Comment: Is there a different way to pass multiple arguments from php script to python?

Comment: So I changed the datatype of the variables in python, from sys to int, and the script worked

Comment: `escapeshellcmd` can’t handle spaces properly, since it doesn’t know whether they came from your string literal or an interpolated variable.

Comment: It's able to handle it. the error was with the python script. changed num_1, num_2 and num_3 to int and it worked