# how do i pass php variable to a python script on a different server

Tags: python, php

This is how to pass php variables to python code in the same folder:

```
<?php
$var1 = "1";
$var2 = "2";
$var3 = "3";
#pass the variables to python
exec ( "python /path/to/python/script.py $var1 $var2 $var3" );
?>
```

Then in your Python script you can read them like this:

```
import sys

print sys.argv[1] # first parameter
print sys.argv[2] # second parameter
print sys.argv[3] # third parameter
```

But how do i do it if if the python script is located in i.e:  https//:example.com/script.py ?

Comment: Instead of exec(), why not send a GET request, eg. with curl, to that url and add the vars as query parameters?

Comment: Duplicate... see here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73395928/pass-multiple-arguements-from-php-to-python?noredirect=1#comment129616755_73395928